# Javascript: Pros and Cons to Closures vs Classes to store context

Tags: javascript, class, closures

In the case I need some state and I need a function that will read/update this state. What are the pros and cons of using closures or declaring a class to to store the state?

Here is an example that generates the nth fibonacci number. The variable m is the state that the fibInner function closure is using.

```
function fib(N) {

    let m = {}

    function fibInner (n) {
        if (m[n]) return m[n]
        if (n === 0) return 0
        if (n === 1) return 1
        m[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
        return m[n]
    }

    return fibInner(N)
};
```

Alternatively we could also declare a class to store the state instead of utilizing closures.

```
function fib(N) {
    return new Fib().solve(N)
};

class Fib {
    constructor(){
        this.m = {}
    }

    solve (n) {
        if (this.m[n]) return this.m[n]
        if (n === 0) return 0
        if (n === 1) return 1
        this.m[n] = this.solve(n-1) + this.solve(n-2)
        return this.m[n]
    }    
}
```

The main thing I would like to discuss is are any of these approaches better in terms of performance (time and space), maintainability, being 
more/less error prone (memory leaks)?

Comment: The immediate difference is that the first one is correct (except for never remembering about 0 and 1), and the second one has Alzheimer's (at every invocation of `fib` you construct a new `Fib`, with a new, empty, memo, then you throw it away after using it once). Either making `Fib` a singleton or making `m` a class property would help.

Comment: @Amadan Thanks, but in the first case we are still at every invocation of fib creating an empty map so I do not see why it is 'correct'? Also, assuming I just wanted to call it once is there a best practice (closure vs class)

Comment: Oh, you’re right, I misread. Both are equally bad. The difference between closures and classes is: closures work in ES5, and allow for private data; class syntax is there since ES6, and private class properties is... ES10 proposal, I think? so at the moment with classes everything is out in the open.